# findAndModify usage in node.js/MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, findandmodify

I have a collection which shows a list of users with their favorite movies.
Here is a sample dataset ...

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("545c08dcc4d2b8a0243dd4db"),
        "mail" : "mickey@mouse.com",
        "name" : "Mickey Mouse",
        "favorite_movies" : [
                {
                        "name" : "The Green Mile",
                        "Year" : "1992"
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Raging Bull",
                        "Year" : "1980"
                }
        ],
        "watched_movies" : [
                {
                        "name" : "The Green Mile",
                        "Year" : "1992"
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Jaws",
                        "Year" : "1976"
                }              
        ]
}
```

Now given _id `545c08dcc4d2b8a0243dd4db` and a movie

```
{
   "name" : "InterStellar",
   "Year" : "2014"
}
```

and if I need to add this to the watched_movies, in Node.js/MongoDB, I believe the only way is to

1. Find the document using Find
2. Do a findAndModify on the found document by appending to the watched_movies array.

Step #2 is based on example here
http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html

Is there a better way to do this ? Specifically can I avoid the step#1 ?

Here is how I'm doing step#2.
But I'm forced to do step#1 to get the "watched_movies" element and then append the new movie to it to construct the `movielist`

```
//try to update
collection.findAndModify(
{'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, //query
[['_id','asc']], //sort order
{$set: {"watched_movies": movielist}}, //replacement
{new: true}, //options
function(err, newObject){
   if(err) {
     console.warn(err.message);
   } else {
     console.log("Updated !! " + JSON.stringify(newObject));
     res.send(object);
   }
 });
```

I am also open to suggestions on improving this schema design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a single `findAnyModify` call by using the [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push) or [`$addToSet`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#up._S_addToSet) array operator to directly add the new movie to the `watched_movies` array:

```
var movie = {
   "name" : "InterStellar",
   "Year" : "2014"
};

collection.findAndModify(
  {'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)},
  [['_id','asc']],
  {$addToSet: {"watched_movies": movie}},
  {new: true},
  function(err, newObject){
     if(err) {
       console.warn(err.message);
     } else {
       console.log("Updated !! " + JSON.stringify(newObject));
       res.send(newObject);
     }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your tip ! $addToSet is great. But this doesn't work with findAndModify.I get this error "exception: nextsafe(): { $err: "can't canonicalize query: badvalue Code: 17287.  But it works with collection.update(), although it doesn't return the updated document.

Comment: @EnnioMorricone I put the sort parameter back and now it tests out fine now.  I didn't realize that was always required.